jest.config.ts file not working with react-scripts test
I am new to Jest and struggling to setup in my React TypeScript Web app. I want to keep all my Jest configuration details in a single file jest.config.ts. I keep getting an unknown long list of errors:
package.json
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "lint": "eslint . --config eslint.config.mjs",
        "lint:css": "stylelint 'src/**/*.{css,scss}'",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "test": "react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.ts"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@eslint/js": "9.5.0",
        "@jest/globals": "29.7.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "6.4.6",
        "@testing-library/react": "16.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "14.5.2",
        "@types/eslint__js": "8.42.3",
        "@types/jest": "29.5.12",
        "@types/jquery": "3.5.30",
        "@types/pluralize": "0.0.33",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.3.0",
        "@types/react-helmet": "6.1.11",
        "eslint": "8.57.0",
        "express": "4.19.2",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "2.0.6",
        "jest": "29.7.0",
        "prettier": "3.1.1",
        "stylelint": "16.7.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "36.0.1",
        "stylelint-scss": "6.4.1",
        "ts-jest": "29.2.3",
        "ts-node": "10.9.2",
        "typescript": "4.9.5",
        "typescript-eslint": "7.13.1",
        "web-vitals": "3.5.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@horat1us/detect-ad-block": "1.0.0",
        "axios": "1.7.2",
        "bootstrap": "5.3.3",
        "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001642",
        "jquery": "3.7.1",
        "moment": "2.30.1",
        "pluralize": "8.0.0",
        "react": "18.3.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "2.10.4",
        "react-device-detect": "2.2.3",
        "react-dom": "18.3.1",
        "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
        "react-intersection-observer": "9.13.0",
        "react-request-fullscreen": "1.1.2",
        "react-router-dom": "6.25.1",
        "react-schemaorg": "2.0.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-smartbanner": "5.1.4",
        "sass": "1.77.8",
        "smart-app-banner": "2.0.0",
        "smart-app-banner-react": "2.0.1",
        "swiper": "11.1.5",
        "ts-interface-checker": "1.0.2"
    }
}

jest.config.ts
import { Config } from "jest";

const config: Config = {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!axios)/"],
    verbose: true
};

export default config;

When running npm test
> myapp@1.0.0 test
> react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.ts

  Invalid testPattern --config=jest.config.ts|--watch|--config|{"roots":["<rootDir>\\src"],"collectCoverageFrom":["src\\**\\*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","!src\\**\\*.d.ts"],"setupFiles":["C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\node_modules\\react-app-polyfill\\jsdom.js"],"setupFilesAfterEnv":["<rootDir>\\src\\setupTests.ts"],"testMatch":["<rootDir>\\src\\**\\__tests__\\**\\*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","<rootDir>\\src\\**\\*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],"testEnvironment":"jsdom","transform":{"^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\jest\\babelTransform.js","^.+\\.css$":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\jest\\cssTransform.js","^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\jest\\fileTransform.js"},"transformIgnorePatterns":["[\\\\\\]node_modules[\\\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$","^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"],"modulePaths":["C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\src"],"moduleNameMapper":{"^react-native$":"react-native-web","^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$":"identity-obj-proxy"},"moduleFileExtensions":["web.js","js","web.ts","ts","web.tsx","tsx","json","web.jsx","jsx","node"],"watchPlugins":["jest-watch-typeahead\\filename","jest-watch-typeahead\\testname"],"resetMocks":true,"rootDir":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp"}|--env|C:\Users\xxx\Documents\myapp\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\build\index.js supplied. Running all tests instead.
  Invalid testPattern --config=jest.config.ts|--watch|--config|{"roots":["<rootDir>\\src"],"collectCoverageFrom":["src\\**\\*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","!src\\**\\*.d.ts"],"setupFiles":["C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\node_modules\\react-app-polyfill\\jsdom.js"],"setupFilesAfterEnv":["<rootDir>\\src\\setupTests.ts"],"testMatch":["<rootDir>\\src\\**\\__tests__\\**\\*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","<rootDir>\\src\\**\\*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],"testEnvironment":"jsdom","transform":{"^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\jest\\babelTransform.js","^.+\\.css$":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\jest\\cssTransform.js","^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\jest\\fileTransform.js"},"transformIgnorePatterns":["[\\\\\\]node_modules[\\\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$","^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"],"modulePaths":["C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp\\src"],"moduleNameMapper":{"^react-native$":"react-native-web","^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$":"identity-obj-proxy"},"moduleFileExtensions":["web.js","js","web.ts","ts","web.tsx","tsx","json","web.jsx","jsx","node"],"watchPlugins":["jest-watch-typeahead\\filename","jest-watch-typeahead\\testname"],"resetMocks":true,"rootDir":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\myapp"}|--env|C:\Users\xxx\Documents\myapp\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\build\index.js supplied. Running all tests instead.
 FAIL  src/utils/functions.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.    
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\myapp\node_modules\axios\index.js:1   
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';  
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      2 | import $ from "jquery";
      3 |
    > 4 | import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
        | ^
      5 |
      6 | import {
      7 |       Age_Rating, Age_Rating_ALL_VAL, AvailabilityProvider, Country, Country_ALL_VAL, FilterSettings,

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)        
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/functions.ts:4:1)

 FAIL  src/utils/classes.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/utils/classes.test.ts:2:1 - error TS1208: 'classes.test.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.

    2 describe("function: contains", (): void => {
      ~~~~~~~~

Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.308 s
Ran all test suites.


https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration

@jonrsharpe I have read through that link but am still unsure what I am supposed to implement. Are you referring to values that are required in my jest.config.ts?

@johnsharpe you can see from the code that the OP supplied that they're using typescript, so the link you provided them with will not help, instead try this.
